# How I disable or uncheck all checkboxes, if one checked in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have to use group of checkboxes in my project.

This is how my HTML look like:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor" value="1"> hairColor-1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor" value="2"> hairColor-2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor" value="3"> hairColor-3
</label>        
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor" value="4" class="any"> any
</label>

<br> 

<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor" value="1"> eyeColor-1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor" value="2"> eyeColor-2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor" value="3"> eyeColor-3
</label>        
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor" value="4" class="any"> any
</label>
```

Using this checkboxes, users can select their preferred selection. But if they select the checkbox text with "any" I need to uncheck all other selection already made within a group. And also if they check that checkbox other chechboxes should not be check.

This is how I tried it using Jquery.

```
$( "body" ).on( "change", ".checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("any")) { //Any checkbox tick
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) { //User checked any
            //Other checkboxes are unchecked
            $(".checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox][name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]:not(.any)").prop("checked", false)
        }
    } else { //Other checkbox tick
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {//User checked another checkbox
            //Any checkbox is unchecked
            $("[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "].any").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
});
```

It's working for me. But my problem is when I change `name` value to `array` type like `hairColor[]` then my code is not working.

Comment: auto-spelling I assume :)

Comment: cmon Alex, that gave me a really good laugh!

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake... This is working fiddle with `name` in `array` type - http://jsfiddle.net/6D9kS/174/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your name attributes contain `[]`, you either need to **escape** them or switch your single/double quote usage like

```
$('[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"].any')
```

```js
$("body").on("change", ".checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox]", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("any")) { //Any checkbox tick
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) { //User checked any
      //Other checkboxes are unchecked
      $('.checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox][name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]:not(.any)').prop("checked", false)
    }
  } else { //Other checkbox tick
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) { //User checked another checkbox
      //Any checkbox is unchecked
      $('[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"].any').prop("checked", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor[]" value="1">hairColor-1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor[]" value="2">hairColor-2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor[]" value="3">hairColor-3
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hairColor[]" value="4" class="any">any
</label>

<br>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor[]" value="1">eyeColor-1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor[]" value="2">eyeColor-2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor[]" value="3">eyeColor-3
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="eyeColor[]" value="4" class="any">any
</label>
```

See [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

I like AmmarCSE's answer, I have upvoted it, but I believe there is certainly room for improvement. You might have other characters in your name attribute and you might have more instances of a character. As a result, I believe a simple function should solve the issue, like this:

```
function escapeSpecialChars(input) {
     return input.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

and then you apply it, like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "change", ".checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    var escapedSelector = escapeSpecialChars($(this).attr("name"));
    if ($(this).hasClass("any")) { //Any checkbox tick
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) { //User checked any
            //Other checkboxes are unchecked
            $(".checkbox-inline > input[type=checkbox][name=" + escapedSelector + "]:not(.any)").prop("checked", false)
        }
    } else { //Other checkbox tick
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {//User checked another checkbox
            //Any checkbox is unchecked
            $("[name=" + escapedSelector + "].any").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6D9kS/178/).